# PHPMailer giving "SMTP Connection failed" error message

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have the following code:

```
require 'bin\PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->From = "[an e-mail address]@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress("[an e-mail address]@gmail.com");

$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

$mail->AltBody = 'sprava';

if (!$mail->send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent";
}
```

And here is the response:

```
    2014-06-11 15:46:34 SERVER 
-> CLIENT: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP v47sm60079970eel.22 - gsmtp 2014-06-11 15:46:34 CLIENT 
-> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2014-06-11 15:46:34 SERVER 
-> CLIENT: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [95.103.53.55] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250 CHUNKING 2014-06-11 15:46:34 CLIENT 
-> SERVER: STARTTLS 2014-06-11 15:46:34 SERVER 
-> CLIENT: 220
    2.0.0 Ready to start TLS Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in C:\dev\localhost_www\bin\class.smtp.php on line 262 2014-06-11 15:46:34 CLIENT 
-> SERVER: QUIT 2014-06-11 15:46:44 SERVER 
-> CLIENT: 2014-06-11 15:46:44 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

How can I fix that? I tried that thing with `php.ini` file but without success.

Comment: turn on ssl in your php. and... what "that thing"? there's many things...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to the issues this this part of the error:

> -> CLIENT: 220
>       2.0.0 Ready to start TLS Warning: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in
>   C:\dev\localhost_www\bin\class.smtp.php on line 262 2014-06-11
>   15:46:34 CLIENT

That means that your local PHP setup does not have `php_openssl.dll` enabled.  You can enable that by going into your `php.ini` & finding a line that looks like this:

```
; extension=php_openssl.dll
```

And uncommenting it:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Save that, restart Apache & all should be good.

And if you want to make sure your are editing the correct `php.ini` file, create a file named `phpinfo.php` in your web root. And then place the following command in there:

```
phpinfo();
```

Then load `phpinfo.php` via a web browser like this; change `http://localhost/` to match your server URL:

```
http://localhost/phpinfo.php
```

When that page loads, it will show you all of your server’s PHP settings. Look for the line that reads `Loaded Configuration File` and change the `php.ini` that is loaded there.

Comment: No. I forgot to restart Apache. Thanks for your answer